# Javascript download a URL - Azure Blob Storage

Tags: javascript, azure, download, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Blob Storage, and I want users to be able to download files.  When a user clicks a file they want to download, I use AJAX to generate a shared access signature and return the URL to download from.  Is there any way for me to then, using Javascript, download the file?  Or is there some other method I can use...  I also would like it to not run server side, as there is no reason to incur unnecessary cost when I should be able to download directly from the URL...

Basically, how Dropbox does it... Is it submitting some form somehow? It doesn't even have to be like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want your users to see `Open/Save As` prompt when they click on the SAS URL.

Assuming my understanding is correct, recently Windows Azure Storage had announced some enhancements. One of the enhancement there is addition of `Content-Disposition` property for the blob which would allow this `Open/Save As` prompt to show when a user clicks on the SAS link for the blob. With `Content-Disposition`, you have 2 options:

1. **Set `Content-Disposition` as blob property**: In this case, whenever user clicks on the SAS link, they will be prompted to save the file. But in this case, they will **always** be prompted so SAS link or not, user would never be able to see the document inline in the browser. You may find this link useful for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee691966.aspx.
2. **Set `Content-Disposition` as part of SAS URL**: In this case, a user will only be prompted when they click on the SAS URL which contains `Content-Disposition`. You may find this link useful for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn140255.aspx.

So assuming you have a png file. In option 1, it will never be displayed inline in the browser, it will be downloaded on the client machine and opened in the registered image viewer on your computer. In option 2, if `Content-Disposition` is set in the SAS URL, the image file will be downloaded on the client machine and opened in the registered image viewer on your computer otherwise it will be displayed directly in the browser.

If you're using .Net, Storage Client library 3.0.0.0 has support for this feature so you don't have to write wrapper around the REST API (but I think you're using PHP ... from your previous question about CORS :)).

Comment: Do you have any idea why the signature doesn't match with the new version?  With literally 100% the rest of the code the same, if $version = '2012-02-12' it generates a good signature, but if I change that to '2013-08-15' it says signature doesn't match. Nothing else has changed yet, but I don't see anything about changing how to build signature for the new version here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn140255.aspx

Comment: Assuming you're writing a wrapper over REST API, Have you included all the new parameters where you're constructing `SignatureString`? See the section titled `Constructing the Signature String` in the link you mentioned.

Comment: It may not be a bad idea to post another question on creating SAS URL using PHP and the latest version of REST API with the code you're using. I'm sure it's going to help a lot of folks.

Comment: Oh. OH. I see.  I was missing a new line :/ silly me -- I am making a writeup anyway that I will post somewhere about all of this... Thank you for all your help Guarav :)

Answer (score 2):

The way that I've done this in the past is by opening a hidden iframe with the url for the download.

Something along the lines of

```
var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
frame.src = url; // your Azure url
frame.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(frame);
```

Note that you'll need to make sure that you don't try to do this on a secure (https) page with an insecure download (http)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid reload/redirection, I use this library :

http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/

*If you need help to set it up* : http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

But if you want to redirect the user, you could use basic thing like :

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com/file.pdf";
```

Comment: And btw if you use jqueryfiledownload don't skip the cookie part otherwise it will not work !

Comment: I just wanted to add that you and the other user were perfectly fine as well -- your answer being a library of his answer -- but the issue lied in Azure's content-distribution header, as outlined in Guarav's post.  I then utilized jqueryfiledownload to download the correct URI with the correct SAS with the correct content-distribution header and it worked wonders :D